# Searing Sous-vide with electric heat gun

Tags: equipment

After looking at various searing approaches incorporating the use of gas torches I wondered if heat guns might be a useful tool for searing. Heat guns are relatively inexpensive and have various tips to adjust the heat pattern. Having used both tools I believe the heat gun might be easier to use in this application. An inexpensive variable output gun can attain either 750  or 1000 degrees F. Has anyone tried this approach?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that it will work. A butane torch can provide a temperature of up to 1700K (1,430 °C; 2,600 °F) (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butane_torch)), whereas I haven't seen any electric ones claiming to go above 600°C (1100°F).

While 600°C seems plenty warm to get a decent Maillard reaction going, it will take much longer than with a higher temperature, and you will probably dry out the underlying layers.

(The 'Searzall' looks like a modified butane torch, rather than an electric heat gun.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The crew at Momofuku in New York invented a heat gun called the Searzall for exactly this purpose. [Bon Appetit](http://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/tools-test-kitchen/article/searzall) has an article on it; they're raising production funds through Kickstarter.

Comment: As Popup mentions in his answer, the Searzall is a torch, not an electric heat gun.

Comment: True, @DrRandy. But on the other hand (s)he talks about a 'heat gun' as an alternative to a 'gas torch'. I can't think of any other alternatives, that would apply here. (Although, re-reading the OP again (and again, and again) I concede that depending on parsing, there's maybe no strict dichotomy in it between the two terms.)

Comment: "Electric" is specified in the title of the question. But of course now we are beating a dead horse.